# Unit test for text parser

Tags: c#, unit-testing, parsing, testing

I'm new at unit testing and I try to test my parser:

```
public static List<tranche> Parse22(string record)
{
    List <tranche> Tranche = new List<tranche>();
    foreach (var i in record)
    {
        var ts = new tranche();
        ts.dealer_name = line.Substring(2, 5);
        ts.invoice = line.Substring(7, 7);
        ts.amount = Decimal.Parse(line.Substring(14, 13));
        ts.vin = line.Substring(46, 17);
        ts.model = line.Substring(63, 4);
        ts.registration = line.Substring(72, 10);
        ts.brutto = Decimal.Parse(line.Substring(95, 13));
        Tranche.Add(ts);
    }
    return Tranche;
}
```

I want to test dealer_name and VIN are correct. But I don't understand what should be at "Assert."

```
[TestClass]
public class ParserTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Parse_LineStarts22_ReturnsVINandDealerNameCorrect()
    {
        string record = testString;
        var res = myParser.Parse22(record);

        Assert.AreEqual() //???
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `line`, why iterate over a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method has two parameter: *expected value* and *actual value*

Because res is a `List` you have to access the item you want to check via the index and then the propety you want to check.

This is an example for the first item in your res `List`.

```
Assert.AreEqual("expectedDealerName", res[0].dealer_name);
Assert.AreEqual("expectedVin", res[0].vin);
```

For more information have a look at the [Assert.AreEqual Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.areequal.aspx)

In my example the `AreEqual(Object, Object)` method will be used.

> Verifies that two specified objects are equal. The assertion fails if
>   the objects are not equal.